# JSON data from API into HTML table

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, request

I want to get the time data and the temperature data (for all 7 days) from JSON (that came after my initial request to an external weather API - open meteo), parse the JSON and populate a HTML table with it. I cant get to populate the table with data.

Below is my code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    th{ 
        color:#fff;
            }
</style>


<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr  class="bg-info">
        <th>time</th>
        <th>temperature</th>
      
    </tr>

    <tbody id="myTable">

    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    var myArray = [
    
    ]

    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=44.32&longitude=23.80&start_date=2022-11-30&end_date=2022-12-06&daily=temperature_2m_max&timezone=GMT',
        success:function(response){
            myArray = response.daily
            buildTable(myArray)
            console.log(myArray)
        }
    })

    function buildTable(data){
        var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
        
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var row = `<tr>
                            <td>${data[i].time}</td>
                            <td>${data[i].temperature_2m_max}</td>
                            
                       </tr>`
            table.innerHTML += row
            
        }
    }

</script>
```

The JSON data that I get

Raw--

```
{"latitude":44.3125,"longitude":23.8125,"generationtime_ms":0.3180503845214844,"utc_offset_seconds":0,"timezone":"GMT","timezone_abbreviation":"GMT","elevation":106.0,"daily_units":{"time":"iso8601","temperature_2m_max":"°C"},"daily":{"time":["2022-11-30","2022-12-01","2022-12-02","2022-12-03","2022-12-04","2022-12-05","2022-12-06"],"temperature_2m_max":[5.9,6.1,8.1,9.5,9.3,7.3,4.3]}}
```

Parsed ---

```
{
"latitude": 44.3125,
"longitude": 23.8125,
"generationtime_ms": 0.3180503845214844,
"utc_offset_seconds": 0,
"timezone": "GMT",
"timezone_abbreviation": "GMT",
"elevation": 106,
"daily_units": {},
"daily": {
"time": [
"2022-11-30",
"2022-12-01",
"2022-12-02",
"2022-12-03",
"2022-12-04",
"2022-12-05",
"2022-12-06"
],
"temperature_2m_max": [
5.9,
6.1,
8.1,
9.5,
9.3,
7.3,
4.3
]
}
}
```

Comment: can you share why your attempt fails, or what is going wrong? Maybe by updating the text of your question, to provide more information.

Comment: Well it showed the 2 arrays but not in the table, just in the dev tools...Someone else found my solution, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function buildTable(data){
        var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
        
        for (var i = 0; i < data.time.length; i++){ // edited
            var row = `<tr>
                            <td>${data.time[i]}</td> // edited
                            <td>${data.temperature_2m_max[i]}</td> // edited                            
                       </tr>`
            table.innerHTML += row
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should be         

for (var i = 0; i < data.time.length; i++)

Because data is not an array so you can't get length, and only do it like that if you are sure data.time and data.temperature_2m_max always have the same length

Answer (score -1):

It works, Thank you!

```
function buildTable(data){
        var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
        
        for (var i = 0; i < data.time.length; i++){ // edited
            var row = `<tr>
                            <td>${data.time[i]}</td> // edited
                            <td>${data.temperature_2m_max[i]}</td> // edited                            
                       </tr>`
            table.innerHTML += row
            
        }
    }
```